# Bulk edit for custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

to make an area like in the picture for what kind of change should I make below

```
<?php

/* Portfolio Custom Post Type */

$args = array(
"label"                         => "Şarkı Sözü", 
"singular_label"                => "Şarkı Sözü Kategorisi", 
'public'                        => true,
'hierarchical'                  => true,
'show_ui'                       => true,
'show_in_nav_menus'             => false,
'args'                          => array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ),
'rewrite'                       => true,
'query_var'                     => true
);
add_action('init', 'Theme2035_lyric_register');  


function Theme2035_lyric_register() {  



global $theme_prefix;

if(empty($theme_prefix['lyrics-page-slug'])) { $theme_prefix['lyrics-page-slug'] = "lyrics"; }

$lyric_slug = $theme_prefix['lyrics-page-slug'];

$labels = array(
    'add_new' => __('Yeni Şarkı Ekle', 'portfolio item', "2035Themes-fm"),          
    'name' => __('Şarkı sözleri', 'post type general name', "2035Themes-fm"),     
    'singular_name' => __('Şarkı sözleri', 'post type singular name', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'add_new_item' => __('Yeni Şarkı Sözü Ekleme', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'edit_item' => __('Şarkı Sözünü Düzenle!', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'new_item' => __('Yeni Şarkı Sözü', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'view_item' => __('Şarkı Sözünü Görüntüle', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'search_items' => __('Şarkı Sözü Ara', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'not_found' =>  __('Henüz hiçbir Şarkı eklenmedi', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('Çöpte hiçbir şey bulunamadı', "2035Themes-fm"),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
);

$args = array(  
    'labels' => $labels,  
    'public' => true,  
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,        
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $lyric_slug, 'with_front' => false ),
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor','thumbnail','comments'),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag'),
    'menu_icon'  => 'dashicons-format-audio',
   );  

register_post_type( 'lyrics' , $args );  
}  

?>
```

I want to add feature album and artist

```
        array(
        'name'     => __( 'Sanatçı adı', 'Theme2035Framework' ),
        'id'       => $prefix."artist_name",
        'type'     => 'select_advanced',
        'options'  => $artist_list,
        'multiple'    => false,
        'placeholder' => __( 'Sanatçı İsmini Seç', 'Theme2035Framework' ),
    ),


    array(
        'name'     => __( 'Albüm Adı', 'Theme2035Framework' ),
        'id'       => $prefix."album_name",
        'type'     => 'select_advanced',
        'options'  => $album_list,
        'multiple'    => false,
        'placeholder' => __( 'Albüm Adını Seç', 'Theme2035Framework' ),
    )
```

https://cdn.r10.net/editor/31364/7ff22d5e9cd73d600c26021f87612d66.jpg

Comment: Avoid placing the code on external servers, from where it can disappear later, [edit question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/337545/edit) and paste it here. Please translate labels so that the pasted code is more readable.

Comment: Look into register_taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is custom taxonomy (which has been mentioned in the comments). Which you create with the [`register_taxonomy()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) function. There is a beginners guide [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/create-custom-taxonomies-wordpress/) if you need it.

You will need to pass in an array of [arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments). The most important is probably `hierarchical` which is true for something like categories, or false for something like tags.

```
<?php
    $object_type = 'lyrics'; // this can be any type including post, page, etc..
    $taxonomy = 'my_featured_artists'; // this could be whatever you want it to be
    $args = array(); 
    $args['hierarchical']=TRUE; // this is probably what you are looking for.
    register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
```

I found a specific example of a taxonomy for music [here](https://generatewp.com/taxonomy/?clone=music-genre-taxonomy). Give it a go and if you run into any specific problems you can always come back and ask more specific questions.